# Visual C++ 2008 Express, list box: Access Items

Tags: visual-c++, listbox, listboxitems

I'm working with VC++ 2008 Express and I want to be able to access the Items of a listBox in order to manipulate optical aspects of various Items by the code.

First, I wrote:

```
listBox1->AllowSelection = true;
```

The compiler didn't accept that.

error C2039: 'set': is no member of 'System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::AllowSelection'

was the comment.

What do I have to do?

Resolving the bug, how is it possible to access Items seleted by the code in order
to change optical aspects (ForeColor, BackColor, Font...)?

Thanks and regards

Uwe

Answer (score 0):

`AllowSelection` is a read-only property. Assign to `SelectionMode` property instead.

If you want to draw each item differently, set `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable`, then handle `DrawItem` event and draw them to taste. There is nothing like a `ListBoxItem` class with `ForeColor` property, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it was that what I was looking for. Well the application asks some questions to the user. At the end, the questions will be presented with the answers of the user in a panoramic overview and according to those answers and the importance given by the user, the font (fore-back colour or normal/bold) of each ITEM (question) changes. Could You pls show me a way how to do that, or is it better to use a RICH TEXT BOX?